# M1 - react-native init - NilClass error occurs

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

Good day,

I have already searched and tried several solutions on the Internet, however, none of them solves my problem or I do something wrong.

The following:

I run a "npx react-native init MyTest".

I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried the following solutions:

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install

Important to know: I did not go into the created order of react-native!

The command "arch -x86_64 pod install" then tells me: "No Podfile found".

But even if I run the command under "cy MyApp/iOS" I don't get the error "No Podfile found", but I get the error:

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Users/myname/Apps/MyApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/myname/Apps/MyApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16. 3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/myname/Apps/MyApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3. 2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/myname/Apps/MyApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Users/myname/Apps/MyApp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
```

I closed my terminal and restart my Mac M1. The error is still there.

I used mac in the version Sonoma 14.0

Edit: I not using Rosetta

I hope someone can help me

Comment: If you do `arch -x86_64` then you _are_ using Rosetta.

Comment: Yes, i used this.

Comment: What cocoa version are you using ?
Tip: Uninstall cocoa pods and reinstall with homebrew.

Comment: I use 3.2.0.
I will try this :) Is it correct that i run the "arch -x86_64 pod install" not in the react-native ios folder?

Comment: I tried this what you wroute. But with same error